# Should I save external data in directory Android/data or data/?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Which is correct,

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      + "/data/com.packagename";
```

or

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      + "/Android/data/com.packagename";
```

if I want to store data in external storage? I see many apps are using the second option, but some use the first path.

Answer (score 3):

You should rely on the API to figure out the directory for you:

```
File externalDir = Context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

[Context.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) will return your 2nd path. Programs that return the 1st path probably hardcoded the path and got it wrong as a result.